# How to fix a odd shift key glitch

Tags: modeling, workflow

This may be a little odd, but everytime I'm on blender, and try to model, I move around the scene, like doing shift f to move, blender does something that it thinks I'm pressing the shift key, or something similar or related like. Quick thing that blender does is everytime I select a individual object, but a select a different object, it selects both of them and I didn't press the shift key. Hopefully I could get some sort of help

Comment: This seems like it might be an issue with your keyboard. Have you had this with any other programs on your computer?

Comment: I might check my keyboard, but no, this bug only happens on blender and not any other progams

Comment: Just to add to that comment, the glitch only happens when I do Shift + (Random Key)

Answer (score 0):

just go into user preferences and change shift key to something else or get a new keyboard.

Comment: Could you elaborate somewhat on part one of your answer?

Comment: Showing works better than telling usually :)